# tortoisegit settings->git->remote not showing

Tags: ssh, key, tortoisegit

I want to use tortoisegit for windows7-64bit.
I have already generated ssh-keys.
I have read many tutorials instructing me how to "make the SSH key be known to TortoiseGit".
Tutorials say that I should go to settings->git->remote, and
fill some fields properly.

The problem is that in my computer, the "remote" options does not show up.
Assuming that was a bug of last version,
I tried to install some previous versions (non-last-ones),
and the problem remained.
I am stuck.

Can someone help me either to make the "remote" option to show,
or to explain me how to make ssh key be known to tortoisegit.

Thanks in advance.

sbVB

Answer (score 11):

In order to see the "remote" option (under TortoiseGit -> Settings) you should launch (right click) TortoiseGit on a folder which belongs to a GIT working copy or on a repository.

So, you have to clone a repository or creating an empty one.

Answer (score 2):

To find the "remote" option you should select a folder which is repository and Right click to select tortoisegit and select pull ,then you can see the "manage remote" on the popu windows,then click it and you can set the remote NOW!

Answer (score 0):

I did this to add SSH keys to tortoise git and it did work well.

If you have an existing .pub file and a private key:
Follow the instructions on this [link](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/putty#puttygen) to generate a .ppk file

1. Download and open PuTTYgen from the PuTTY Download Page.
   Click Load.
2. Load Your Private Key.
3. Locate the private SSH key that you have downloaded.
   Note: You will need choose to display All Files* from the menu to the right of the File Name field.
4. Enter the password for your SSH Key
5. Click the Save private key button to create the ppk file.
6. Once you have the .ppk file, you can follow this [link](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-faq.html).
7. Start PuTTY, go to Connection->SSH->Auth and select your ppk key.
8. Now navigate to Session, select Default Settings and hit Save.

I was able to clone the repo, pull and push changes.

Note:
1. You must have added the public key in your git provider like github etc..

2. If you already have a .ppk file, you can directly start with the second leg.

I still do not have a remote option as you said above and I don't think it matters to me anymore. ;)

Edit: This probably depends in this choice you make while installing Tortoise git:

[image]