# TortoiseGit: Settings "remote" missing. How can I set SSH key without having a cloned repository?

Tags: ssh, tortoisegit

I'm trying to clone a repository for which I need an SSH key. The "remote" option in the settings is only available *after* having a clone.
Is there any way to set this SSH key without cloning from command line or using a different tool?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703538/tortoisegit-settings-git-remote-not-showing). This question is not a duplicate, since there, you already need to have a git repository (cloned or created).
I also read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/198614/216289) and the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open the clone dialog, there is the option "Load Putty" key. There you can specify your ssh key.

[image: Clone dialog]

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-clone.html

Please also see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html.

Comment: I need to buy a pair of glasses. Thank you!